# Search engine query impoving Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, search, laravel-5

Hello everyone and happy new year!
So I implemented a simple search engine for my application, so the users can search for products and buy what they like. Up until now, the queries focus on only 2 columns; title and description.

This is my query:

```
Product::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->get();
```

This is the products table which is being queried:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('imagePath');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->string('category',30);
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->integer('XS');
        $table->integer('S');
        $table->integer('M');
        $table->integer('L');
        $table->integer('XL');
        $table->integer('XXL');
    });
```

I can modify my query like this:

```
Product::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->
orWhere('description', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->
orWhere('category', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->
orWhere('price', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->
orWhere('quantity', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->
orWhere('XS', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->
orWhere('S', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->
orWhere('M', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->
orWhere('L', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->
orWhere('XL', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->
orWhere('XXL', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")->get();
```

Now my concern lies on 2 things;
How can I make the query distinguish whether a user is searching for a product with a name that contains xl in it or a product eg a t-shirt which is xl size or price instead of quantity since both of them are integers?

Also if a user hits the spacebar in search field (_), it returns all products in database. If a user hits the spacebar twice (__), it returns a message "there are no such products etc", like it should. Is there any way to prevent that?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can add some label match input or select in your page, these label like size/price.  when you submit the search form, the form data like this:

```
{
    title:'t-shirt',
    category:'clothes',
    size:'xl',
    min-price:100,
    max-price:200
}
```

Then your query look like:

```
$query = Product::where('title', 'LIKE', $title})->
orWhere('description', 'LIKE', $titlel)->
orWhere('category', 'LIKE', $category)->
orWhere('price', '>', $min_price)->
orWhere('price', '<', $mac_price)->
orWhere('quantity', 'LIKE', $quantity)->

//judge the params have size
if(params_size_haved){
    $query->orWhereNotNull($size)    
}

$query->get();
```

**The code just is a quick demo，You can depend on the specific use of the amendments.**

#### About space:

you can use `trim($search_str)` and `str_replce()` delete the space in search field, and this should before query execution.

#### More suggestions：

the table is not pretty well. maybe you can google `sku table design` to get more information

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will check it out